# Remover dados do banco com GRAILS E GORM

Tags: mvc, grails, groovy, gorm

Estou aprendendo um pouco de `GRAILS` e estou com o seguinte problema consigo exibir as informações de alguns usuarios cadastrados normalmente mais quando tento exclui-los não consigo e não recebo erro algum, segue o codigo

```
def delete() {
    Usuario user = Usuario.get(params.id)
    user.delete()
    redirect action:"index"
}
```

se eu imprimo na tela essa variavel `user` eu tenho acesso a todas as informações do usuario porem ao tentar remove-lo nada acontece

estou enviando o `id` assim `delete/id`

//EDIT estou com o mesmo problema ao fazer update nos dados..

Answer (score 1):

descobri uq era tava precisando mandar um `flush:true` junto pq o `hibernate` não atualiza os dados instantaneamente